# Assigning user Roles on Nova using Spatie Laravel Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-permission

I am currently using spatie laravel permissions package in a laravel 5.8 project and using Nova for admin.

I want the super admin user to be able to assign a role to selected users from the nova dashboard. This is how I have attempted to do it, by using nova actions. I created a `GrantAdminRole` action and doing the role assingment inside the handle method like this

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    foreach ($models as $model) {

        // grant user admin role
        $model->assignRole(['admin']);
    }

    return Action::message('User has been assigned Admin role.');
}
```

Then in my `app\Nova\User` action method I am using the `GrantAdminRole` action

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        (new GrantAdminRole)->canSee(function ($request) {
            return $request->user()->hasRole(['super-admin']);
        })
    ];
}
```

Now when I try to assign the role, I get an error message

> Sorry! You are not authorized to authorized to perform this action

How can I fix this? I am thinking I need a policy but can't figure out how what the policy should look like.

Comment: Rather than building all this logic, you can use this Nova Tool that does it: https://github.com/vyuldashev/nova-permission